# NG-STYLE with custom condition not firing

Tags: angularjs, function, conditional-statements, ng-style

I have the following item in a remote datasource (greatly simplified)

```
[
{
    "id": "3",
    "card_name": "Free Beer!",
    "count": "1"
}
```

]

I have a DIV with an NG-REPEAT (again greatly simplified)

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cardDetails">
 <h1>{{card.card_name}}</h1>
 <button ng-style="set_hide(card)">Claim Me</button>
</div>
```

and the following in my controller

```
    $scope.set_hide = function (card) {
    if (card.count > 0) {
        return { display:none }
    } else {
        return { display:block }
    }
}
```

so basically if the count of this card is not zero (1+) the button is supposed to display:none and vanish

The rest of the info (ie the card name) renders as expected and if I also add `{{card.count}}` that shows as 1 as expected

but nothing happens, at all. No errors, just nothing

Why is my ng-style not firing

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to hide the button. A simpler way to do this will be not to use function set_hide().

You can just insert ng-hide attribute to the button element.

`<button ng-hide="card.count > 0">Claim Me</button>`

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: ng-hide will still keep the element in DOM, but will just not show it. Probably a better solution would be ng-if.

Comment: akshar:  ng-hide, ng-if  -> the difference is negligible. How could you know is 'probably a better solution' ???  Better of why? Make more unnecessary operations with DOM ?? Very strange advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
$scope.set_hide = function (card) {
  if (card.count > 0) {
    return { display:'none' }
  } else {
    return { display:'block' }
  }
}
```

You are missing the quotes around 'none' and 'block'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but ng-hide solves my issue. Thanks for taking time to asnwer though